# Load php extension

Tags: linux, php, magento

relatively new to servers, have just installed apache and mysql-server and php on centos 6. I keep getting this error when trying to install a software called Magento however:

> PHP Extensions "pdo_mysql" must be loaded.

Anyone have any clue what I should do to fix this? You can see how the current setup is here:

208.111.35.80/test.php

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What linux distro are you using?

Comment: vps provider just calls it centos 6 but uname -a shows 'Linux baobei.sanjose.com 2.6.35.4-cloud #6 SMP Thu Jun 30 05:29:07 PDT 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the PHP MySQL connector extension.

If using RHEL/CentOS or derivative the fix would be `yum install php-mysql`.

Answer (score 2):

Just install php-mysql

```
yum install php-mysql
```

Then restart apache

```
service httpd restart
```